# How to unchecked and check the Nebular Check box dynamically after rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nebular, ngx-admin

I am using a nebular theme checkbox in the Angular 8 App.

```
 <nb-checkbox  [checked]="enable_checked" (checkedChange)="enable($event)"  >Enable </nb-checkbox>
```

i am updating the checkbox using  `"enable_checked"` Boolean .When the component loaded it works fine but when I changed the value dynamically of BOOLEAN(`"enable_checked"`) it is not getting updated at the front end but the boolean is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working you must change it like this :

```
<nb-checkbox [checked]="enable_checked" (checkedChange)="enable($event)" >Enable </nb-checkbox>

<button (click)="changeCheckbox()">Set false</button>
```

For more information: [Docs](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/checkbox/api#nbcheckboxcomponent)

Typescript :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  enable_checked = true;

  changeCheckbox() {
    this.enable_checked = false
  }
}
```

Stackblitz Example: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nb-checkbox-checked)